# Notation - indicies reusing in summation - visibility of indices

Tags: multivariable-calculus, summation, notation

Is it OK to use a variable in an equation both as regular index and, independently from that, as summation index in a sum?

$ P(A_n | B) = \frac{P(B|A_n)P(A_n)}{\sum_{n=1}^N P(B|A_n)P(A_n)} $

Or this one:

$J_{ij} = \frac{\partial E_{f} \{ x^i \}}{\partial \eta_j} =
\int_\mathbf{R} \Bigg( \frac{\partial c(\vec{\eta})}{\partial \eta_j} x^i
\exp\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^L \eta_i \, x^i \right \} + c(\vec{\eta}) \,
x^i \, x^j \, \exp\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^L \eta_i \, x^i \right \}
\Bigg) d x$

Comment: No ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Technically, yes, but (1) if you need the regular index in the summation you’re screwed and (2) your readers will probably hate you.